# f:ajax does not render p:dataTable inside p:layout

Tags: ajax, jsf, layout, primefaces

i have a dataTable and possibility to delete row by click to delete image.
[image]
When I clicked it the data is deleted but the table is not rendered

Here is my code:

```
<p:fieldset id="knowledgeBases" legend="#{appMsg.knowledge_base}">
    <p:layout style="width:auto; height:800px;">
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="kbCenter">
        <p:dataTable id="kbDataTable" var="kb" value="#{KnowledgeBaseBean.kbList}" sortMode="multiple"
                     rows="10" paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
            <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{KnowledgeBaseBean.onFilter}" update = ":formId:kbDataTable"/>

            <p:column style="width:2%">
                <h:commandLink title="#{appMsg.common_delete}" id="deleteImage" onclick="return confirm('#{appMsg.del_warn_current_record}')" >
                    <h:graphicImage name="images/new_design/image13.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;text-align: center" />
                        <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@form"
                                listener="#{KnowledgeBaseBean.deleteListItem}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </p:column>                 
            ...
```

Comment: what is the scope of your `KnowledgeBaseBean`, try reloading page `F5` does it rendered now?

Comment: yes it's rendered when i reload page

Comment: What is the scope of bean `KnowledgeBaseBean`

Comment: the scope is ViewScoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my bean. When i delete the object from the database i forget to delete this object from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you use full page layout the problem may be that you have a form around the layoutUnit. Do it the other way around. From the Primefaces 4.0 user guide p. 262:

> When working with forms and full page layout, avoid using a form that contains layoutunits as generated dom may not be the same. So following is **invalid**.

```
   <p:layout fullPage="true">
    <h:form>
           <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100">
                 h:outputText value="Left Pane" />
           </p:layoutUnit>
           <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                 <h:outputText value="Right Pane" />
           </p:layoutUnit>
    </h:form>
```

```
A layout unit must have it’s own form instead, also avoid trying to update layout units because of same reason, update it’s content instead.
```

Further explanation [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2614).

Comment: thanks for the replay it was useful to read. But unfortunately it does not helped, because me layout has a style instead of setting fullPage to true, so the form should work as expected. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with p:commandLink, p:graphicImage and p:ajax instead? Are you sure it gets deleted and don't just show the deleted-message? Maybe the onclick() eats the ajax event. There is a primefaces component for exactly this type of confirmation, I dont remember the name right now

Comment: i did not try p:commandLink, p:graphicImage and p:ajax, but i will. Please refresh your memory, maybe i need exactly this component